# Why type aliases in C# cannot be used in another alias?

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement, type-alias, c#-12.0

After C# 12 (.NET 8), all types can be aliased:

```
using A = int;
using B = string;
using C = Dictionary<int, string>;
```

However, it cannot be written as

```
using A = int;
using B = string;
using C = Dictionary<A, B>;
```

Is this a bug or just a feature?
Is there any workaround?

Comment: which value will this bring to you?

Comment: Can you name a practical use case so that we could think of possible workarounds?

Comment: @NineBerry Very long names can be aliased? Eg `Dictionary<LongName1, Dictionary<LongName2, List<LongName3>>>` could be aliased.

Comment: @NineBerry
Just the same reason as using constants instead of hard coded literals: to make the code more readable and maintainable. Nothing concerned with the function of program. So if it cannot be achieved easily, I decide to just let it go.

Comment: @Maytham Fahmi
The code will be more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation of the compiler Error CS0246](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) explains that

> A `using` alias directive does not use the `using` directives in the
> source code file to resolve types.

So, the other aliases defined in the same source code file are not visible while declaring new aliases.